# Photo manager with tagging and metadata

Tags: linux, photography, media-manager, exif

Is there a photo manager software in linux, that can store image metadata including image tags in the image itself and not an extra database?

I tried DigiKam, but it tells me that the data would be put in an external database.

Apart from storing metadata inside the Exif header, I need just the basic functions of a photo manager software - viewing, sorting, tagging. Tagging should be possible through a GUI though.

Comment: AFAIR [gThumb](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gthumb/features) can do that (I'm using it but never tried editing tags; but [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/gThumb) seems to confirm it). Ships from most distri's repos, so you can use your packaging tool (apt/yum) to install it.

Comment: darktable appears to store the metadata in xmp sidecar files, sadly.  So far the only app I have found for this is Adobe Bridge (running on my Mac), which is closed source but is gratis, and DOES have the capability to put the metadata into the image file itself.

Comment: and  i assume, you can read back the metadata only with adobe bridge and not any other program?

Comment: What is wrong with digiKam it stores tagging and metadata in central database **and** in jpg-photo-file.

Comment: @k3b -  well, if its "and", then feel free to post this as an answer. I stored the tags using digikam and unfortunately could not read them again via digikam from another computer. This means, that it was required to have a database to restore the image tags.

Comment: digikam has a setting where you can tell where to store the changes in image.jpeg.xml or in image.jpeg